# Can semantic-ui form validation rules on one field be conditional on a different field?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, semantic-ui

Let's say I have a form with two fields. I'd like the following to be possible:

Submit the form empty - Validation succeeds
Both fields contain data - Validation succeeds
Field one has data, field two empty - Validation succeeds
Field one empty, field two has data - Validation fails

Is there a way to do this?

My server code already validates for this, but I'd love to be able to prevent the client from hitting the server if it doesn't have to.. but if that's not possible, is there a way to pass form validation error messages to the form as the page loads?

Thanks!!

Answer (score -2):

you can use regex for complex validation rule

first add some code to form.js, this file is accessible in:

Semantic-UI-master\Semantic-UI-master\dist\components\form.js

after this code

```
// is most likely an email
email: function(value){
  var
    emailRegExp = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", "i")
  ;
  return emailRegExp.test(value);
},
```

add this code

```
// is most likely an my regex
regex: function(value,reg){
  var
    regexRegExp = new RegExp(reg, "i")
  ;
  return regexRegExp.test(value);
},
```

and use it in your semantic ui code, like this

```
firstname: {
    identifier: "first_name",
    optional: true,
    rules: [
        {
            type: "regex[^[a-zA-Z -]+$]",
            prompt: "First name can only consist of letters, spaces and dashes"
        }
    ]
}
```

for example this is my code to validate a complex cod contain only 10 digit or alphabet in mix

```
            $("form[data-id=\"2\"]").form({
                v: { identifier: 'active_code', rules: [{ type: "regex[^[a3-z8]{10}$]", prompt: 'کد فعال سازی خود را وارد کنید'}] }
            },
            {
                inline: true,
                on: 'blur',
                transition: 'swing left',
                duration: 1000,
                onSuccess: formOnSuccess
            }
            );
```

the complete code

```
        $("form[data-id=\"1\"]").form({
            f: { identifier: 'family', rules: [{ type: 'empty', prompt: 'فامیلی خود را وارد کنید'}] },
            e: { identifier: 'email', rules: [{ type: 'email', prompt: 'ایمیل خود را وارد کنید'}] }
        },
            {
                inline: true,
                on: 'blur',
                transition: 'swing left',
                duration: 1000,
                onSuccess: formOnSuccess
            }
        );
        $("form[data-id=\"2\"]").form({
            v: { identifier: 'active_code', rules: [{ type: "regex[^[a0-z9]{10}$]", prompt: 'کد فعال سازی خود را وارد کنید'}] }
        },
            {
                inline: true,
                on: 'blur',
                transition: 'swing left',
                duration: 1000,
                onSuccess: loadPersonal
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't think it addresses my question. What I want to do is have the validation check if field1 is empty AND field2 is checked, then fail validation. Is that possible?

Comment: if you want to mix field to validate, field 1 optional AND field 2 in required AND if field 1 checked then field 2 is Optional, so i don't know. but you should know what a field is required or not. in other word requiring  a field must not depend on other field,  i edit end of  my answer